# AMD Laptop: Boot sometimes fails

Tags: boot, amd, encryption, thinkpad

I seem to have fixed this issue and posting my answer below.

TLDR: this seems to be common problem with AMD machines.

---

I am stuck with a boot problem I struggle to narrow down:

- I installed elementary OS on a new laptop*, after running on my old laptop no problem
- Only difference is that I added drive encryption this time

**Current behavior**:

- When booting, the system *sometimes* gets stuck after I enter the password for disk decryption.
- In these cases, it takes me to a black screen with the white cursor, but stays there until I press the power button to restart - there is no error message I see, but some updates flash by very quickly (do not know how to slow them down)
- This does not happen every time, and eventually the computer boots & works fine

**Questions**

--> I am really confused here regarding where to debug: does this potentially have to do the decryption part? Or the OS? And why is it not consistent?

--> Sometimes it will take me to the screen where I can pick between different Linux kernels / recovery mode: is this something I should adjust?

Any pointers are much appreciated, as I don't even know where to start on this one... Thanks!

*Lenovo T495, AMD® Ryzen™ 5 Pro 3500U, 24GB of RAM, 1TB Samsung SSD

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is an Ubuntu / kernel issue with some newer AMD CPUs/GPUs, see e.g. [here](https://blog.vx.sk/archives/287)

Users describe intermittent boot fails, also  behavior differing between running on battery vs plugged in .

This was fixed for me and other users by [updating the kernel](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/06/install-kernel-5-7-ubuntu-linux-mint/) to 5.7.

Thought I would post this here in case useful.